# Request for help to find a closed-form expression for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+15)^2}{(2n+11)^3\sqrt{(2n+13)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

By the comparison test, the series converges.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+15)^2}{(2n+11)^3\sqrt{(2n+13)}}=l$$
$$l\simeq0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304288146572043505953641$$
(74 digits displayed)

I would like to know if it is possible to find a closed-form expression for $l$.

**Edit**

I used a PARI/GP function ([sumnum](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/ref/Sums__products__integrals_and_similar_functions.html#sumnum)) to compute an approximate value of $l$:

```
 gp > #
    timer = 1 (on)
 gp > \p 74
    realprecision = 77 significant digits (74 digits displayed)
 gp > sumnum(n=0, (2*n+15)^2/(2*n+11)^3/sqrt(2*n+13),sumnuminit([+oo,-1.5]))
 time = 15 ms.
 %1 = 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304288146572043505953641
 gp > sum(k=0,97,binomial(-1/2,k)*(zetahurwitz(k+3/2,11/2)+4*zetahurwitz(k+5/2,11/2)+4*zetahurwitz(k+7/2,11/2)))/2/sqrt(2)
 time = 62 ms.
 %2 = 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304288146572043505953641
 gp > \p 400
    realprecision = 404 significant digits (400 digits displayed)
 gp > sumnum(n=0, (2*n+15)^2/(2*n+11)^3/sqrt(2*n+13),sumnuminit([+oo,-1.5]))
 time = 1,078 ms.
 %3 = 0.3948319867064057092267020945886965694553266494738330428814657204350595364122729251535099721677148100865638904442238183504239633022203492259575689525638233484603909542517059855919506733374353926795281971622814159109637670427399334579124116308394274900167149611375839262362929064148759669151317574581119034347857659144521214162698550204609725028401793070583608454779328237780415473232520384318559950198
 gp > sum(k=0,537,binomial(-1/2,k)*(zetahurwitz(k+3/2,11/2)+4*zetahurwitz(k+5/2,11/2)+4*zetahurwitz(k+7/2,11/2)))/2/sqrt(2)
 time = 3,532 ms.
 %4 = 0.3948319867064057092267020945886965694553266494738330428814657204350595364122729251535099721677148100865638904442238183504239633022203492259575689525638233484603909542517059855919506733374353926795281971622814159109637670427399334579124116308394274900167149611375839262362929064148759669151317574581119034347857659144521214162698550204609725028401793070583608454779328237780415473232520384318559950198
```

Comment: Do you have any reason for assuming that it does indeed have a closed form?

Comment: whomever can answer this deserves a bounty

Comment: Just out of curiosity : how did you compute $l$ (what tool) and how many terms did you sum (I suppose billions) ? Cheers.

Comment: To Claude Leibovici. Even if previous comments suggest that it may be impossible to find a closed-form expression for l, your contributions are very interesting. Kudos to you.

Comment: Did you use *zetahurwitz(.)* in your initial calculation to get $l$ ? If you used the original summation, how many terms did you use for $74$ decimal places ?

Answer (score 10):

*Not a closed form but a rather good approximation of it*.

Rewriting as $$a_n=\frac{(2n+15)^2}{(2n+11)^3\sqrt{2n+13}}=\frac{(2n+15)^2}{(2n+11)^3\sqrt{2n+11+2}}=\frac{(2n+15)^2}{(2n+11)^{\frac 72}\sqrt{1+\frac 2{2n+11}}}$$ we can  write
$$\frac 1{\sqrt{1+\frac 2{2n+11}}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}\frac{2^k}{(2n+11)^k}$$ and then face  summations of terms
$$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n+15)^2}{(2n+11)^{k+\frac 72}}=2^{-k-\frac{3}{2}} \left(\zeta \left(k+\frac{3}{2},\frac{11}{2}\right)+4 \zeta
   \left(k+\frac{5}{2},\frac{11}{2}\right)+4 \zeta
   \left(k+\frac{7}{2},\frac{11}{2}\right)\right)$$ and then for the considered summation
$$\Sigma=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n+15)^2}{(2n+11)^3\sqrt{2n+13}}$$  So, the partial sums
$$\Sigma_p=\frac 1{2\sqrt 2}\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k} \left(\zeta \left(k+\frac{3}{2},\frac{11}{2}\right)+4 \zeta
   \left(k+\frac{5}{2},\frac{11}{2}\right)+4 \zeta
   \left(k+\frac{7}{2},\frac{11}{2}\right)\right)$$ Computing 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \Sigma_p \\
  5 & 0.39483148307398830445048206504782536496698034745960346801382376024 \\
 10 & 0.39483198676616324735777911451436673248113391244073226133701558847 \\
 15 & 0.39483198670639658527502248284985700122310258168712958250026452734 \\
 20 & 0.39483198670640571076206255275333399438974388443990146144695977886 \\
 25 & 0.39483198670640570922643131344152894240169346679460070946980052257 \\
 30 & 0.39483198670640570922670214360763624644791582367286943018650562365 \\
 35 & 0.39483198670640570922670209457967764179263574295643280410747243813 \\
 40 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869824722904384200792304484978282169 \\
 45 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656914069678422236918330533995116 \\
 50 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945538601634396101492730552390 \\
 55 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532663821679612114844784572 \\
 60 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947597620995355367822 \\
 65 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383263347402134364 \\
 70 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304295989988132 \\
 75 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304288145065669 \\
 80 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304288146572333 \\
 85 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304288146572043 \\
 90 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304288146572044 \\
 95 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304288146572044 \\
 100 & 0.39483198670640570922670209458869656945532664947383304288146572044
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

In order to know how many terms have to be added for $p$ significant digits, since we face an alternatin series, consider
$$a_k=\frac 1{2\sqrt 2}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k} \left(\zeta \left(k+\frac{3}{2},\frac{11}{2}\right)+4 \zeta
   \left(k+\frac{5}{2},\frac{11}{2}\right)+4 \zeta
   \left(k+\frac{7}{2},\frac{11}{2}\right)\right)$$ A quick and dirty linear regression (built for $10 \leq k \leq 1000$ by steps of $10$) shows that (and this is an almost perfect fit)
$$\log_{10}(|a_k|)=-0.740989\, k-2.51445$$ So, for $p$ exact digits, we need to sum up $\lceil 1.35\, p -3.40 \rceil$ terms (just as reflected by the values in the above table). For $74$ digits as given in the post, then $k=97$ which has been verified. Using the original summation, I suppose that billions of terms have been added (summing from $n=0$ to $n=10^9$ leading to $0.39481$). This look normal since, for large values of $n$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1-\frac{3}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ which is extremely slow.

Comment: What field of math is this? it's fascinating

Comment: Claude Leibovici's work is often, as in this case, quite impressive.

Comment: @martycohen. Be sure that, this coming from you, I really appreciate ! Thanks.

Comment: @clathratus. At least, part of the ones I do enjoy ! Cheers.